# Quartz.Net - Quarterly starting from today

Tags: c#, scheduling, quartz.net

How do you create a trigger that is triggered every 3 months (quarterly) starting today.

I though i could do something as simple as

```
tr = TriggerUtils.MakeHourlyTrigger(2190);
// (365 / 4) * 24 hours = 2190
```

I don't think this is best way to solve this. I though there might be some fancy cron trigger way of solving it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fields in cron are

1. Seconds
2. Minutes
3. Hours
4. Day-of-Month
5. Month
6. Day-of-Week
7. Year (optional field)

So you might like

```
0 0 0 1 */3 ?
```

Which will fire every 3 months on the first of the month at midnight.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_6.html

Comment: just to confirm, so if i wanted to run something at 7am every 3 months start from today it would look like this `0 0 7 29 */3 ?` also what happens if person sets up this trigger in November 30th, it would skip February wouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah it would skip February, that is why it is better to run it on the 1st. Almost every month has a first day, except Notember.

Comment: do you think there is a way of solving this. I thought that maybe in my Execute method, i will check when is the "triggerNextDate" and if its invalid I would change trigger to valid one.